system of nonlinear ODEs using OCTAVE
I want to solve a system of ODEs in OCTAVE. But the final plots are not the same as the page 66 plots of the thesis in the link below:
https://www.ideals.illinois.edu/items/18410
my code:
https://www.mycompiler.io/view/H9TNMcNT6mY
    ```function main
    t=linspace(0, 4000, 8000);
    x0 = [1;5*3.14/360;5*3.14/360;0.175;0;0];
    x = lsode (@f, x0, t);
    subplot(2,2,1);plot(t,x(:,1));title("l");legend("fgo")
    subplot(2,2,2);plot(t,x(:,2));title("theta")
    subplot(2,2,3);plot(t,x(:,3));title("phi")
    subplot(2,2,4);plot(t,x(:,4));title("dl")
    endfunction;
    function xdot = f(x,t);
    T=0.000644;
    O=0.001049;
    xdot=zeros(6,1);
    xdot(1)=x(4);
    xdot(2)=x(5);
    xdot(3)=x(6);
    xdot(4)=T+x(1)*(x(5)+O)^2*cos(x(3))^2+x(1)*x(6)^2-O^2*x(1)*(1-3*cos(x(2))^2*cos(x(3))^2);
    xdot(5)=-2*x(4)/x(1)*(x(5)+O)+2*x(6)*(x(5)+O)*tan(x(3))-3*O^2*cos(x(2))*sin(x(2));
    xdot(6)=-2*x(4)/x(1)*x(6)-(x(5)+O)^2*cos(x(3))*sin(x(3))-3*O^2*cos(x(2))^2*cos(x(3))*sin(x(3));
    endfunction; ```

I am appreciate if you could help me with this situation,

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include the code (as opposed to linking it). Also pay attention to this FAQ.

Please use semi-colons to suppress the automatic output. Then when only the intended output remains, do you get the same or a different error?

I have deleted the line "x=zeros(1,6)" and finally could draw the plots. However, the final plots are not the same as plots on page 66 of the thesis on the link below:  https://www.mycompiler.io/view/H9TNMcNT6mY
